# Quartz Scheduler not updating on remote server

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I created an MVC application, in which I implemented Quartz scheduler to pull exchange rate at a specific time in the morning. it works on Dev, but when I upload to the remote server it not working.

The problem is on the remote server the Quartz Scheduler is not triggering at all, thus the exchange rate cannot be retrieved.

is there something needed to be copied to the remote server
is there a setting I need to set.

this is how I implemented the pulling of the exchange rate.

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static async Task Start()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity("name", "group")
            .UsingJobData("Name", "Bob")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
            (s => 
            s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
            .OnEveryDay()
            .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(14,08))
            )
            .Build();
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        await scheduler.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        //await scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
}


public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var rate = GetRate();

        if (rate != 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Exchange Rate: {rate}");

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Value FROM AppConfigurations WHERE Name = '{AppConfigarationItems.FallBackExchangeRate}'", connection);

                object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (value == null)
                {
                    var sql = $@"INSERT INTO AppConfigurations (Name,Value,DoubleValue,LastUpdateDate)
                             VALUES ('{AppConfigarationItems.FallBackExchangeRate}','{rate.ToString().Replace(',', '.')}',{rate.ToString().Replace(',', '.')},'{now}')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    var sql = $@"UPDATE AppConfigurations 
                             SET Value = '{rate.ToString().Replace(',', '.')}',
                             DoubleValue = {rate.ToString().Replace(',', '.')},
                             LastUpdateDate = '{now}'
                             WHERE Name = '{AppConfigarationItems.FallBackExchangeRate}'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
            }
        }
    }




    protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA");
        AbpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config"));
        base.Application_Start(sender, e);
        JobScheduler.Start().Wait();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may or may not have something to do with IIS and the way it handles App pool recycling

This has worked for me in the past.

1. Go to IIS manager -> Application Pools -> Create a new pool, name it whatever you want
2. Select Scheduler pool -> advanced Settings
3. In General section, at Start Mode, Select AlwaysRunning or true (depending on version of IIS)
4. In Process Model Section-> Idle Timeout(minutes) set to 0 (meaning: No Idel timeout)
5. In Recycling section -> Regular time Interval set to 0 (meaning: no recycling)
6. Deploy your Quartz site into that application pool.
7. Send one request to the pool to "wake your app up" and it will run until u stop it.

There are also some tools that you can install on hosting server like [Keep Alive server for IIS 6.0 and 7.5](https://keepalive.codeplex.com/) it will keep the application alive after app pool recycling and eliminate the need to change or set up too many configurations.